# Sum and append totals to CSV files in python

Tags: python

I have the following data in a csv file:

```
symbol,name,amount
A,john,2
D,mary,6
E,bob,9
m,liz,-8
p,peter-2
```

I'm new to programming and python specifically, how do I append two sum at he bottom of the table, one showing the sum of the positive amounts and the second showing the sum of the negative amounts.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: you may make some loop , if it lower than 0 or higher than 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with csv files, then you should take a look at Python's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module which helps with splitting each row into a list of columns. Each entry is loaded is treated as a string so you will need to first convert the 3 column (numbered 2 in Python as 0 is the first) to an integer.

The following reads each line in, calculates the running totals and writes each line to an output file, added the final row holding your totals:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    header = next(csv_input)
    csv_output.writerow(header)

    sum_positive = sum_negative = sum_a = 0

    for cols in csv_input:
        csv_output.writerow(cols)
        value = int(cols[2])

        if cols[0] == 'A':
            sum_a += value
        if value >= 0:
            sum_positive += value
        else:
            sum_negative += value

    csv_output.writerow([
        "A total {}".format(sum_a),
        "Positive total {}".format(sum_positive), 
        "Negative total {}".format(sum_negative)])
```

This would give you an output file as follows:

```
symbol,name,amount
A,john,2
D,mary,6
E,bob,9
m,liz,-8
p,peter,-2
A total 2,Positive total 17,Negative total -10
```

Comment: Thanks so much Martin. How would  I go about excluding"A" from the total and including a separate line with "A" total and secondly find the differences between current totals and similar total in a separate file- lets say one is named Monday and second file is named Tuesday.

Comment: I have modified it to calculate `A` separately. For extra lines just write each entry with its on `writerow`. You should give it a try and if you need further help you could start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

For something simple like this, you can just extract the last value in the CSV file.

First, find the values

```
plus, minus = 0
with open(fileName) as f:
    for l in f:
        v = int(l.strip('\n').split(',')[-1])
        if v >0 : plus += v else minus += v
```

Then, just append values to the file ...

```
with open(fileName, 'a') as f: 
    f.write('positive: %, negative: %d\n'%(plus, minus))
```